# Is it safe to pass an `std::string` temporary into an `std::string_view` parameter?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdstring, string-view

Suppose I have the following code:

```cpp
void some_function(std::string_view view) {
    std::cout << view << '\n';
}

int main() {
    some_function(std::string{"hello, world"}); // ???
}
```

Will `view` inside `some_function` be referring to a `string` which has been destroyed? I'm confused because, considering this code:

```cpp
std::string_view view(std::string{"hello, world"});
```

Produces the warning (from `clang++`):

```
warning: object backing the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression [-Wdangling-gsl]
```

What's the difference?

(Strangely enough, using braces `{}` rather than brackets `()` to initialise the `string_view` above eliminates the warning. I've no idea why that is either.)

*To be clear, I understand the above warning (the `string_view` outlives the `string`, so it holds a dangling pointer). What I'm asking is why passing a `string` into `some_function` doesn't produce the same warning.*

Comment: The life-time of temporary values is until the end of the full expression. In the case of the first example, the end of the full expression is when the `some_function` call have finished. So for that case it's valid.

Comment: clang is right to issue the warning. `std::string_view view(std::string{"hello, world"});` creates a string_view you must never access the data of, if you want to avoid undefined behaviour, since the char array `view` refers to is gone at the end of the full expression. The other use will work, since the temporary string survives until `some_function` has returned.

Comment: If you change your parameter type from `std::string_view view` to  `const std::string_view& view`, does that make the compiler warning go away?

Comment: @fabian Thank you, but why is it that `std::string_view view{std::string{"hello, world"}}` (i.e. with braces) doesn't produce a warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`some_function(std::string{"hello, world"});` is completely safe, as long as the function doesn't preserve the `string_view` for later use.

The temporary `std::string` is destroyed at the end of this full-expression (roughly speaking, at this `;`), so it's destroyed after the function returns.

---

`std::string_view view(std::string{"hello, world"});` always produces a dangling `string_view`, regardless of whether you use `()` or `{}`. If the choice of brackets affects compiler warnings, it's a compiler defect.

Answer (score 3):

`std::string_view` is nothing other than `std::basic_string_view<char>`, so let's see it's [documentation on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view):

> The class template `basic_string_view` describes an object that can refer to a constant contiguous sequence of `char`-like objects with the first element of the sequence at position zero.
>
> A typical implementation holds only two members: ***a pointer to constant `CharT`*** and a size.

The part I have ***highlighted*** tells us why clang is right about `std::string_view view(std::string{"hello, world"});`: as others have commented it's because after the declaration is done, `std::string{"hello, world"}` is destroyed and that underlying pointer that the `std::string_view` holds dangles.

Clearly that's just a *typical implementation*, but since we know it is correct, it tells us at least that the standard doesn't require any implmentation to do something special to keep temporaries alive.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to pass an `std::string` temporary into an `std::string_view` parameter?

In general, it isn't necessarily safe. It depends on what the function does. If you don't know, then you shouldn't assume it to be safe.

Knowing the definition of the function as shown, it is safe to call the example function with a temporary string.

> Will view inside some_function be referring to a string which has been destroyed?

Not in this case, because the temporary argument string - which the string view refers to - hasn't been destroyed.

---

> What's the difference?

The parameter of the function has shorter lifetime than the lifetime of the temporary passed as the argument. The lifetime of the string view variable is longer than the lifetime of the temporary argument passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Just as others have said, `some_function(std::string{"hello, world"});` is totally safe since it passes it by value and stays in scope until the function ends. If safety is all you are concerned with, that will do, if performance could be an issue, I'll recommend using an rvalue reference here like so:

```
void some_function(std::string_view&& view)
{
    std::cout << "rval reference: " << view << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    some_function(std::string{"hello, world"});
}
```

**R-value references** are great if you are going to use `some_function()` mainly for temporary values.

Comment: I thought about that, but I think `string_view` is so small that moving it wouldn't make much of a difference. I think being able to blithely copy `string_view`s around is the whole point in them. `sizeof(string_view)` only returns 16 to me, after all.